# React 17 will destroy my deprecated lifecycles code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
componentWillrecieveprops(){
....}

componentWillMount(){
..
}
```

i used this lifecycles in multiple component and i cant replace with didupdate or such other stuff so my question is after react 17 my code will raise any issue and iam also using **UNSAFE**

Comment: From the [blog](https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/08/08/react-v16.9.0.html): The new names like UNSAFE_componentWillMount will keep working in both React 16.9 and in React 17.x. However, the new UNSAFE_ prefix will help components with problematic patterns stand out during the code review and debugging sessions.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet you *can actually* convert your code to not use any of the essentially deprecated lifecycle functions. There are many tutorials and articles written that cover these conversions to more correct/less buggy react component code.

Comment: yes Drew reese but i said there is multiple component where iam using this . so i cant change

Comment: As easy as that: if you cannot adapt to the new lifecycle methods, you have to stop using React in the future. Though, I'd also bet you can (as Drew wrote), you are just not willing to do it.